# Codeigniter send email error 404 on web page

Tags: php, .htaccess, email, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

I'm testing a web example... I create a contact form on this direction, you can try to send an email and then view inspect-console or inspect-network:

http://www.novaderma.cl/site2/

It gives an error 404, "the requested URL was not found on this server" ...I don't know what's happening...here is the .htacces file, please help me !!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does your virtualhost have `AllowOverride All` set (assuming you are using Apache)?

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean ...where should I find this ?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? Do you have ssh access to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In htaccess file in the root directory add this rewrite rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
```

Also in codeigniter Config folder -> autoload.php file add url helper:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: TY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! man I have this problem almost 3 days...you're a hero !! cheers!!

Comment: If you have issue for session then autoload 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below the code in your htaccess file...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase //
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Rather than just providing code, could you explain how and why this solves the OP's problem?